# Restart node server automatically after patch operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, yaml

I am making a patch operation on a yaml file of mine. I am testing my apis through postman. After patch operation, the yaml file gets updated. But when i do get operation , the previous value of the field which was updated is being displayed. But if i restart the node server and do get, the updated values are displayed.

Is this a bug? How do i solve this so that when i do 'get' , i always get updated values?

Comment: Hi, can you post your patch action? And also if it calls a function to write the file, could you post that function too? Kind of hard to know what you've done so far, without the code.

Comment: Posting will be tedious as the object is big. I just wanted to update a field. By the way u can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780367/updating-yaml-file-through-patch-method-not-working for the code where i am carrying out the patch operation